# Fourier transform of a non-integer power

Tags: fourier-transform

I have to find the first (at least the first) term of the Fourier expansion of the following function:
$$f(t)=a^\alpha|\cos(\Omega t+b)|^\alpha sgn(\cos(\Omega t+b))$$
where $a$ is a real and positive constant, $b$ a real constant and $\alpha$ un real in $]0;2[$. $\Omega = 2\pi f_0 = 2\pi/T$ with $T$ the period.

What annoys me is this power $\alpha$ which is not necessarily an integer. I don't know how to tackle the problem.

Comment: Start with transforming your function to a form without the powers. How do you compute the non-integer power of a number?

Comment: I use the same formula as for an integer power: $a^b=e^{b\ln(a)}$

Comment: Ok. So fill that into your function. That's your first step.

Comment: OK, it's perhaps not so diffucult... I try. The first coefficient is $a_1 = \frac{a}T \int_{-T/2}^{T/2}e^{\alpha\ln|\cos(\Omega t+b)|+i\Omega t}sgn(\cos(\Omega t+b))dt$. Then, I cut the range $[-T/2;T/2]$ according the sign of $\cos(\Omega t+b)$ and try to integrate on the different parts.

Comment: Hummmm, I thought I had glimpsed a way, but finally it's not that easy

Comment: I tried to translate variable to "eliminate" $b$ and then to translate variable (-T/4) so that $sgn(...)$ is positive on the first half part of the period and negative on the second one and get: $a_1 = \dfrac{ae^{-b-T/4}}T \left( \int_{-T/2}^0 e^{\alpha\ln|\cos(\Omega t)|-i\Omega t}dt
-\int_0^{T/2} e^{\alpha\ln|\cos(\Omega t)|-i\Omega t}dt \right)$

Comment: Cool. Should there not be an imaginary value in that exponent? You're shifting $f(t)$, that's a multiplication with a complex exponential in the Fourier Domain... Next, in the first integral you can replace $\tau=-t$, you can then bring the two integrals into one, and I think the complex exponential goes away (not sure, I'm doing this without a pen). That should make it possible to apply standard integration rules to solve the rest.

Comment: In fact, in order to take the $sgn(...)$ correctly into account, the domain is splitted as: $a_1 = \dfrac{ae^{-b}}T \left( \int_{-T/4}^{T/4} e^{\alpha\ln(\cos(\Omega t))-i\Omega t}dt
-\int_{T/4}^{3T/4} e^{\alpha\ln(-\cos(\Omega t))-i\Omega t}dt \right)$. I didn't succeed in going back to standard integration rules.

Comment: At the end, I get $
a_1 = \dfrac{2ae^{-b/\Omega}}T \int_{-T/4}^{T/4} e^{\alpha\ln(\cos(\Omega t))} e^{-i\Omega t}dt$, so very close to the first form (this result could have been guessed) and I'm still stuck very near to the beginning

Comment: See #311 in [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Distributions). It seems that it is indeed more complicated than I thought. It involves the Gamma function...  And #312 is the signum function.

Comment: Do note though that $\Omega \ne \omega$ (the former is a constant). And the way you removed $b$ is not right, I think. Write out $f(t-b/\Omega)$ and use the shift property of the Fourier transform.